# Spring boot Camel problems when using rest post to send a message to rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have a spring boot application that publish a rest endpoint to receives xml messages using apache camel, below the relevant part of the code corresponding to the configuration of the route:

```
        restConfiguration()
            .component("servlet")
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
    
        rest("/api/").description("REST Message Endpoint Service")
            .id("rest-producer-route")
            // Accept post requests at /api/message
            .post("/message")
            // request in xml format             
            .consumes("application/xml")
            .to("direct:remoteService");

        from("direct:remoteService") 
            // RABBIT_URI = "spring-rabbitmq:%s?routingKey=%s&arg.queue.autoDelete=false";
            .to(String.format(CamelConfiguration.RABBIT_URI, "coreEngine", "coreEngine"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(201));
```

When trying to send a message in xml format using Postman, after about 30 seconds I get a 500 error, with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpReplyTimeoutException: Reply timed out
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.AsyncRabbitTemplate$RabbitFuture$TimeoutTask.run(AsyncRabbitTemplate.java:762) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

However on the rabbitmq server the message was successfully saved to the coreEngine queue.

I don't need any transformation to be done, the goal of the endpoint is simply to receive messages in xml format and store them in a rabbitmq queue.

From what I could see, an AsyncRabbitTemplate is used, would that be the cause of the problem? What should I do to configure it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the exchange pattern by default is expecting a reply, hence camel is using the `AsyncRabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive`. If you just want to fire and forget, set the exchange pattern to `ExchangePattern.InOnly` for Camel to use `RabbitTemplate.send`.

You code should be changed to,

```
from("direct:remoteService") 
            // RABBIT_URI = "spring-rabbitmq:%s?routingKey=%s&arg.queue.autoDelete=false";
            .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, String.format(CamelConfiguration.RABBIT_URI, "coreEngine", "coreEngine"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(201));
```

Refer the Apache Camel SpringRabbitMQProducer source code
[SpringRabbitMQProducer](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/5b89f48b9565421d59cd37bbcaa84695e668649f/components/camel-spring-rabbitmq/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/springrabbit/SpringRabbitMQProducer.java#L110)

Comment: I applied the change you suggested in my code and it works like a charm!. Thank you very much for your help @Srini, I have been trying to solve this for more than a week without any luck.